# The requested URL /ad/AD84567858 was not found on this server

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have Created a Website using PHP and Html. This Website will be posting classified Ads. I have created common php to get a profile of the Ad. ( That Means when I click the ad it will redirect me to a new page ).

It works fine in Localhost but when I upload in the server it gives the error 
**Not Found
The requested URL /ad/AD84567858 was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

Its seems to be the API PHP I gave it creates a new directory but I can't find it

Not Found
The requested URL /ad/AD84567858 was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: did you check if the prefix to URL was not a local one?

Comment: Are you using some framework that does router job ?

Comment: yes it is not a local one